# How to see typescript source for simple classes in chrome dev tools when using webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

I have an angular application using typescript and webpack.
I have turned source maps on in my `tsconfig.json`.

If I go into the Sources tab in Chrome Dev Tools, I can see expand the node labelled `webpack://` and find the typescript source files for components and services etc., but not for simple model classes.

I can repro the same behaviour using the Angular Tour Of Heroes webpack sample:
https://github.com/michaelbazos/tour-of-heroes-webpack

For example, the `HeroService` source can be found here:
webpack://./src/app/hero/hero.service.ts?555d

I would expect to find the source for the `Hero` class in the same location, but it is not there?

Why is it not showing, and how can I view the source for the `Hero` class and set breakpoints etc.?

Comment: can you try hitting command(ctrl)+P and then searching fir your file in the sources tab?

Comment: Ctrl-P and searching does not find it, but thanks anyway that is a handy feature I did not know about!

Comment: okay i made a sample project and had one observation if you create a new object from  that model class in some other component/service(or any file) it wont be visible. Even simply importing the file wont work you have tho use the new keyword

Comment: Sounds buggy. Can you file a ticket at https://crbug.com?

Comment: @KayceBasques Done, thanks: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=762753